# How to list two joined tables info by name (some with name, some possible empty)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select

I have two tables like these

```
Invoice   (invoice_no, invoice_date, customer_id, ...),  
Customers (customer_id, customer_name, ...)
```

Now what I want to do is list invoices ordered by customer name.

```
SELECT b.customer_name, a.*
FROM Invoice a, Customers b
WHERE a.customer_id=b.customer_id
ORDER BY b.customer_name
```

but problem with this sql is that if there are invoices without `customer_id`,
how can I list those invoices first and invoices with `customer_id` by `customer_name` asc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `LEFT JOIN` instead.

"kinda" weird. How come there are some invoices that without customer? To whom are you issuing it? Anyway, here's the query.

```
SELECT  a.*, b.*  // SELECT only the columns you want
FROM    Invoice a
        LEFT JOIN Customers b
            ON a.customer_ID = b.customer_ID
```

To fully gain knowledge about joins, kindly visit the link below:

- [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  
    a.*, 
    b.customer_name
FROM    Invoice a
LEFT JOIN Customers b ON a.customer_ID = b.customerID
```

Use joins instead of FROM tablea, tableb. 
Because this will fetch cartisian product from both tables unless you restrict them with WHERE

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
 SELECT * FROM Invoice,customer where Invoice.customer_id=customer.customer_id ORDER BY IF(Invoice.customer_id is NULL , Invoice.customer_id, ~Invoice.customer_id) ASC
```

Comment: what is this? `~Invoice.customer_id` i tried to run the statement but it generates unknown random numbers. Anyway, the OP is not interested on the ordering of data.